# Variable timestep, am I misunderstanding it?

Tags: java, timing

I asked a question previously about why the movement of my player didn't look smooth, and I was suggested to do this.

> If you want (or need) to reduce CPU usage, you can keep a count of time elapsed since the previous frame, and if it's not yet time to run a frame, Sleep for one millisecond, otherwise run the frame.

However, after doing so, my player moves around 3-4x as fast (rough estimate) as it should. What I'm confused about though, is that my movement is based on the delta time, which accumulates to between 1000-1005 milliseconds per second. I thought that having a variable timestep meant that the game updates should go the same speed whatever the frame rate. Am I wrong, or am I doing something wrong?

**Main loop**

```
private static final int UPDATE_RATE = 60;
private static final float UPDATE_PERIOD = 1000F / UPDATE_RATE;

private void mainLoop() {   
    long beginTime, timeTaken;
    float timeLeft;
    while (state == State.PLAYING) {
        beginTime = System.nanoTime();

        update();
        repaint();

        timeTaken = System.nanoTime() - beginTime;
        timeLeft = (timeTaken / 16000F);
        if (timeLeft < UPDATE_PERIOD) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
        }
    }
}

private void update() {
    p.move(deltaTime);
}
```

**Movement algorithm:**

```
public void move(float deltaTime) {
    if(left && !right)
        xPos -= 250*(deltaTime/1000);
    if(right && !left)
        xPos += 250*(deltaTime/1000);
}
```

**Delta time calculation (every time repaint is called):**

```
        long currentTime = System.nanoTime();
        deltaTime = (currentTime - previousTick) / 1000000F;
        previousTick = currentTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand your problem but I think you are actually decreasing your game's performance by sleeping one milisecond ,  you should put the thread to sleep as much as TimeLeft ,this will increase performance dramatically because it schedules the next time to repaint the frame in a more effective way

Comment: That's what I was doing before but I was told it was inaccurate and I should do it this way.

Comment: Well you can use Timer class it's better than threads in this way

Answer (score 0):

I've found my problem. Since I was calculating delta time when repaint was called, it was changing faster than update was called, meaning it varied a lot moving it faster than it should have.

If anyone else ever has this problem, calculate the delta time in your **main loop**.